# Alternatives to "too...to"

Tags: negation

I know that "too..to" in "I am too busy to go" means I can't go. But can I use other expressions in the place of "too" to have the same effect?  For example, do any of the followings have a negative meaning (i.e. I can't attend your meeting)?

1. I am very busy to attend your meeting.
2. I will be in another meeting at the same time to attend your meeting.
3. I am occupied by other things to attend your meeting.

Are there any other usage patterns like the "too..to" that the "to" part automatically has a negative meaning? Otherwise, I feel I have to use longer expressions like "I am very busy that I can't attend your meeting". Any way to simplify this type of "...that..." expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

None of your three sentences is correct. *I am too busy to go* means *I am **so** busy that I can't go*.

*I am very busy* would have to be followed by *so [therefore] I can't go*, making it longer - and similarly with the other two examples.

Please note that it would sound rather rude to say "I'm too busy to attend your meeting", as though you don't consider it important. It's better to say something like "I'm afraid I won't be able to attend because of my other commitments."

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. It's very useful.